# Query always returns previous value?

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql

This is my first attempt in creating C# desktop application and SQL Server database using LINQ to SQL. Everything went just good, until..

I always got previous value of a table, even though I surely I already update the table, and check the value did change in MSSQL table.

What possibly be the cause of this?

My code are as follows:

**A. Open a StockAdjusment form**

```
StockAdjustment stockAdjustment = new StockAdjustment();
stockAdjustment.prepareForm(product);
```

**B. Inside `prepareForm()` I call the code to query Current Quantity for the selected product**

```
inventory = db.Inventories.Where(i => i.ProductID == product.ID).Single();
numCurrentStock.Value = inventory.Current_Quantity;
```

**C. After stockAdjustment form Close, I store the new stock adjustment**

```
if (stockAdjustment.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    db.InsertInventoryChange(stockAdjustment.inventory.ID, product.ID, stockAdjustment.stockChange, stockAdjustment.currentStock, stockAdjustment.Date, stockAdjustment.Message);
    db.SubmitChanges();
    readData();
}
```

The `readData()` method works just fine. It will display a new stock adjustment, and also the current quantity of the product did change. I also check in the SQL Server tables, it did change.

**D. But, every time I open a new StockAdjustment dialog, it will always display old value of Current Quantity.**

It will able to display the real value, only when I close the application, and restart it.

Somehow I think this is my application code issues, not LINQ. But I have no idea..

Any suggestion?

Comment: You use LINQ to SQL, and not Entity Framework (LINQ to Entities). Why?

Comment: Because I am unaware of :) It's not the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is `db.InsertInventoryChange` a stored procedure call? If it is, my layman's understanding is that LINQ to SQL won't track any value changes resulting out of the call for you (as opposed to directly updating an entity via the DataContext as LINQ to SQL's tracking will know about that), so calling:

```
db.SubmitChanges();
```

Is redundant because the LINQ to SQL DataContext is not aware that you've made a change and likely submits nothing and does not update its internal values. So when you do:

```
db.Inventories.Where(i => i.ProductID == product.ID).Single();
```

You'll get the previous value because LINQ to SQL didn't know about the change and so didn't update the values it has been tracking.

If you're holding onto your `DataContext` instead of creating a new one each time, you could consider [refreshing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.refresh.aspx) before doing your `db.Inventories.Where(i => i.ProductID == product.ID).Single();` call, for example:

```
db.Refresh(RefreshMode.OverwriteCurrentValues);
inventory = db.Inventories.Where(i => i.ProductID == product.ID).Single();
numCurrentStock.Value = inventory.Current_Quantity;
```

There's probably a more elegant way to call `Refresh()` so you don't clobber absolutely everything but my experience here is limited.

Comment: Really enlightening! I got to try first, and then report back to you. Yes, it's a stored procedure, maybe I should create an OUT variable for it...

Comment: @swdev. No you should really work with temporary context instances. One instance per unit of work.

Comment: @GertArnold : ow, what will be the problem if I am not doing it? Well, I treat context instances as a Singleton. so it only got one instance throughout my application. It's a bad practice?

Comment: @GertArnold : I've try using local datacontext instances, but the problem remain. But, after I use this line of code from @nkvu, `db.Refresh(RefreshMode.OverwriteCurrentValues);` it works as expected! thanks

Comment: Sure it is bad practice. It's not impossible, but you already bumped into the first problem (needing refresh time and again). Plus contexts get bloated the longer you use them. I suggest you read about "context life cycle".